# Responsive rule for text in html

Tags: html, text, responsive-design

I'm having trouble with text on my website. As the containers are responsive, I have to manage somehow to get the text responsive as well. I can't find anything concrete about that on the internet. It seems to be a rule reserved for front-enders only... Does anyone knows what have to be done to get responsive text without using javascript libraries ? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Shouldn't involve javascript, just your run-of-the-mill css `@media` queries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for text I use 'em', it's simple to use and works fine.

```
p.myDiv {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

I will explain you how this works:
1 em is equal to 16px(this amount can be changed). you can use the console to get the exact value, for exameple: if you want a `p` font-size to be 20px you simply divide 20/16 and the console will return 1.25. The 1.25 you will have to put it on `font-size` with 'em' after.

You can use 'em' for all types of sizes like borders, font sizes, widths, heights...

but if that don't helps you can simply use @media () {} and adjust the text with them.

hope this helps ;)

Comment: Thanks, using the both methods works seems to be a good solution

Answer (score 0):

What about using size in % ?
e.g.: font-size:20%; of the element. Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS media queries to apply different styles to the text based on the viewport width.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can just use `max-width` and `min-width` for the division of the text.

```
#text {
     max-width: 1000px;
     min-width: 500px;
}
```

Does it work ?